# Using NuSoap in Symfony 2 to send data as XML to a third-party WS

Tags: php, xml, web-services, symfony, soap

I'm trying to send some form data to a CRM using a SOAP webservice (third-party) that requires a XML response.

I'm using Symfony 2, implemented [noiselabs/NoiselabsNuSOAPBundle](https://github.com/noiselabs/NoiselabsNuSOAPBundle) to use NuSoap instead of the built-in SOAP client because I need HTTP Basic Auth to retrieve the WSDL (and looks like it does not work with the classic SOAP client).

Then I built a Service that looks like this :

```
public function send(Contact $contact)
{
    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><lead xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></lead>');
    $xml->addChild('firstName', $contact->getName());
    $xml->addChild('lastName', $contact->getSurname());
    $xml->addChild('companyName', $contact->getCompany());
    $xml->addChild('country', $contact->getCountry());
    $xml->addChild('city', $contact->getCity());
    $xml->addChild('email', $contact->getEmail());
    $xml->addChild('phone', $contact->getPhone());

    $lead = new \stdClass();
    $lead->xml = $xml->asXML();

    $url = 'https://my.url.com/CRM?wsdl';
    $client = new \nusoap_client($url, true);
    $client->setCredentials($this->login, $this->password, 'basic');
    $client->response_timeout = 5000;
    return $client->call('SendAndForget', array('param' => $lead->xml));
}
```

I'm supposed to send this :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:SendAndForget>
         <tem:message>
           <![CDATA[
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
             <lead xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <firstName>Name</firstName>
               <lastName>Surname</lastName>
               <companyName>Company</companyName>
               <country>US</country>
               <city>City</city>
               <postcode>23231</postcode>
               <email>info@mail.com</email>
               <phone>+0123456789</phone>
              </lead>
           ]]>
         </tem:message>
        </tem:SendAndForget>
     </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But I keep having this error and I can find any solution :

```
ErrorHandler ->handleError ('8', 'Array to string conversion', 'C:\wamp\www\XXX\vendor\fergusean\nusoap\lib\class.soap_transport_http.php', '971', array('data' => false, 'cErr' => 'Failed to connect to my.url.com port 10443: Timed out', 'err' => 'cURL ERROR: 7: Failed to connect to my.url.com port 10443: Timed out<br>url: https://my.url.com:10443/CRM?wsdl<br>content_type: <br>http_code: 0<br>header_size: 0<br>request_size: 0<br>filetime:
    -1<br>ssl_verify_result: 0<br>redirect_count: 0<br>total_time: 42.198<br>namelookup_time: 0<br>connect_time: 0<br>pretransfer_time: 0<br>size_upload: 0<br>size_download: 0<br>speed_download: 0<br>speed_upload: 0<br>download_content_length:
    -1<br>upload_content_length: -1<br>starttransfer_time: 0<br>redirect_time: 0<br>redirect_url: <br>primary_ip: <br>', 'k' => 'certinfo', 'v' => array()))
```

Can anyone see what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, not a solution but a workaround, I've locally imported the WSDL file, so I don't need to authenticate. Using the built-in SoapClient seems to work like a charm now.

```
public function send($lead)
{
    $client = new \SoapClient($this->file);
    return $client->SendAndForget($lead->xml);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
public function send(Contact $contact)
{

    $params = array(
                    "firstName" => $contact->getName(),
                    "lastName" => $contact->getSurname(),
                    .....
                );

    $url = 'https://my.url.com/CRM?wsdl';
    $client = new SoapClient($url);
    $client->setCredentials($this->login, $this->password, 'basic');
    $client->response_timeout = 5000;
    $client->__soapCall("SendAndForget", $params);
}
```

Comment: If you want, pm me the wsdl url and I will see if I can help

Comment: You can't PM on Stackoverflow :)